# ASP.NET routing ignoreRoute does not work

Tags: asp.net, routes, ignoreroute

I can't exclude non-existing files from the routing system. I am dealing with this code in a Web Forms scenario:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{   
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.gif/{*pathInfo}");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.jpg/{*pathInfo}");   
  Route r = new Route("{*url}", new MyRouteHandler());
  routes.Add(r);
}
```

When I debug

```
public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    string path;

    IHttpHandler page;

    try
    {
        path = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("url");
        LogFile(requestContext, path);
    }
```

path still contains non existing gif files, jpg etc 
I want to exclude all files that have an extension if that’s possible

Is something wrong with the code above? Is the order correct, i.e. add routes.IgnoreRoute entry prior to adding a route to RouteCollections?

Comment: No luck with my below answer?

Answer (score 1):

In Web Forms, you can use the [StopRoutingHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.stoproutinghandler.aspx).  In the following example,    routing will be ignored for files in the /images folder like http://yoursite.com/images/xyz.jpg

```
routes.Add(new Route("images/{resource}", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

Answer (score 0):

`IgnoreRoute` is an extension method of ASP.NET MVC `(System.Web.Mvc`) - does not work in Web Forms.

Do this:

```
routes.Add(new Route("{resource}.gif/{*pathInfo}", new MyIgnoreHandler()));
```

Map your other routes to your regular handler.

You should remove the "mvc" tag from this question.